# Run Breeze with Web.API v.1 and EF6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, breeze

I am looking at implementing Breeze into one of my web projects.  Currently, the client has set up their project to run under MVC4 and Web.API v.1 with an Entity Framework 6 backend.

Looking at the Breeze web site, the instructions talk about running with Web.API v.1 and EF 4 or 5, or using Web.API v.2 and EF 6, but not my scenario.

Is it possible to run in this config or do I HAVE to run Web.API v.2 to get things to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but we have made no effort to make that particular combination work and are unlikely to try. The possible MS technology combinations are endless. We live in DLL hell as it is and we can only support what we perceive to be the main paths.

However, Breeze is all open source and you are welcome to try it yourself. The source code is in the repo. Have at it.

Personally, I would try to persuade your client that moving to Web API v2 is a necessity.